# Highcharts- chart does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, getjson

I am new to using highcharts, and web development. I am displaying the data from a REST API. I have a chart `chart1` which is inside the `getJSON`method. This chart displays the data as expected. However, the other chart `chart`, which is outside, and after the `getJSON` method does not display the data.

`console.log()` after the `getJSON` method that show the data to be put on the chart is updated, as expected. Why does `chart`(which should display the ambient light) not work?

```js
$(function updat() {
  var url = "https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var humid = [],
    date = [],
    high=[],
    day=[],
    chanceOfRain=[],
    humid_final = [],
    day_final=[],
    high_final=[],
    chanceOfRain_final=[],
    Itemss=[],
    SortedItems=[]
    var htmlText='';

  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    $(json['Items']).each(function(i, data) {
      //Store indicator name
      
      // fill the date array
      humid.push(data.humidity);
      // fill the string data array 
      date.push(data.Date);

      high.push(data.high);
      day.push(data.Day);
      chanceOfRain.push(data.chanceOfRain);

    });

    //unsorted array
    Itemss=$(json['Items']);
    //console.log("ITEMS",Itemss);

    //sorted array- date
     date.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});

    // Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return  date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});

     console.log("Sorted Days", date);
    Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});
     console.log(" Sorted ITEMS",Itemss);
    ////////

    ///////
    // query send string that we need to convert into numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < humid.length; i++) {
      if (humid[i] != null) {
        humid_final.push(parseFloat(humid[i]));
        high_final.push(parseFloat(high[i]));
        day_final.push(parseFloat(day[i]));
        chanceOfRain_final.push(parseFloat(chanceOfRain[i]));
      } else {
       humid_final.push(null)
      };
    }

    //sorting the arrays
    day_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
   // console.log("Sorted day_final", day_final);

    humid_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});


    //ACTIVITY LOG
    var h1 = [10, 20, 30, 40,50,60];
    var t1 = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
    var activ= document.querySelector('.activ');
    for(var i=0; i<h1.length;i++){
      activ.innerHTML += `<p>Temperature was ${t1[i]} degrees and humidity was ${h1[i]} % `;
    }




var chart1 = new Highcharts.chart({
       credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
      chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'temp&humid',
        marginBottom: 100
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature and Humidity'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: day_final //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
      },
      series: [{
       name: 'Temperature',
        data: chanceOfRain_final,
        color:'#646569' //
      },
      {
        type:'line',
        name:'Humidity',
        data: day_final,
        color:'#c5050c' 
      }]
    });

var chart2=  Highcharts.chart('stacked', {

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      height: 250,
      width: 400,
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Today's Light and Water Sources"
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Water', 'Light']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Natural',
        data: [7 , 6],
        color:'#c5050c'
    }, {
        name: 'Automatic',
        data: [ 3, 4],
        color: '#646569'
    }]
});

  }); //getJSON method
 //setTimeout(updat, 3000);

    console.log("high_final!",high_final);
    
    var chart = new Highcharts.chart({

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            height: 200,
            type: 'spline',
            renderTo: 'light',
            marginBottom: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: ' Ambient Light'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: day_final //.reverse() to have the min year on the left
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'light level',
            data: high_final, //
            color: '#9b0000'
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src= "Ag.js"></script>

<div id="light" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
<div id="temp&humid" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
<div id="stacked"> </div>

<div id="parentContainer" style="margin-left:400px; width: 200px; margin-top: -19%" >

 <div id="currentSatus"><center><b>Current Status</b><center></div>
 <br>
 <div id="temp" style="background: #72D923;padding-top:10px; height: 30px"><font face='verdana'><center>Temperature</center></font> </div>
 <div id="hum" style="padding-top:10px; background: red; height: 30px"><font face='verdana'><center>Humidity</center></font></div>
 <div id="water" style="background:#72D923;padding-top:10px; height: 30px "><font face='verdana'><center>Water</center></font></div>
 <div id="ligh" style="background: red; padding-top:10px; height: 30px"><font face='verdana'><center>Light</center></font></div>
 </div>

<div class=" activ" id="log" style="margin-left: 600px; text-align: center; margin-top: -16%"><center><b>Activity Log</b></center> </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to print the value of this console == "Sorted Days" ???

Comment: @MaulikBhatt, I want the Highchart "chart" to make a graph of "high_final"

Comment: In addition to @Daniel W answer below, you can put your third chart in `setTimeout()` function [setTimeout API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/48ey8my7/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the last chart is, that it is initialized before the getJSON function gets the data from the server. The chart1 and chart2 charts are initialized in the success callback, when the data is received from the server.

You could check it in the jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

If you put the third chart into the success callback, it would work.